# Bind datagrid to property of selected item in other datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a class that contains a list of a different type of items.
When an Item in datagrid1 is selected, the list in the selected item should be displayed in datagrid2.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?
So far, I've been trying to do it in SelectedItemsCollection.CollectionChanged event handler, but it seems to me there might be a way to do it via databinding (either in xaml or programmatically in the ViewModel).

Comment: does your data context have 2 list, or does the object that datagrid1 is bound to have its own list of its sub objects?

Comment: @Bryan This one: "... the object that datagrid1 is bound to have its own list of its sub objects?"

Answer (score 2):

Bind the SelectedItem property of the first DataGrid to a source property of your view model:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />

private YourType _selectedItem;
public YourType MySelectedItem
{
     get { return _selectedItem;; }
     set { _selectedItem; = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

...and the ItemsSource property of the second DataGrid to the sub property of the item that is selected in the first one:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding MySelectedItem.TheCollectionProperty}" />
```

Make sure that your view model class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and raises the PropertyChanged event when the "MySelectedItem" source property is set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

This is how to do this using the MVVM design pattern.

You could also bind the ItemsSource property of the second DataGrid directly to the SelectedItem property of the first one like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.TheCollectionProperty, ElementName=dataGrid1}" />
```

Note that for this sample code to work the type of your items in the first DataGrid, i.e. "YourType" in the sample code above, must have a public property called "TheCollectionProperty" that returns an IEnumerable of the items that you want to display in the second DataGrid.

Comment: Getting the ViewModel to process View Data breaks MVVM, so unless he needs the selected item in the ViewModel for business logic then you shouldn't pass the selected item from the View to ViewModel just so that the View can Show it, it should instead be bound directly to a View object

Comment: Binding the SelectedItem property of an ItemsControl to a source property of a view model certainly doesn't break the MVVM pattern in any way whatsoever...the view model is responsible for the application logic (but not the business logic) in an MVVM application.

Comment: if you are binding to the Element directly then the NotifyPropertyChanged call is not needed

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) then you can bind to the `CurrentItem` property (using the "\" operator) and `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`

Example using ListView

```
<DockPanel >
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding ItemCollection}" />
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=/field1,Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvs}}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvs}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding field1}" Header="Feild1"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding field2}" Header="Field2"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding field3}" Header="Field3"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding field4}" Header="Field4"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

This also has the effect of unlocking the advanced sorting, grouping and filtering functions